# How can I restrict UITextField on UIAlertController to take only number with specify range?

Tags: swift

I have created an UIAlertController with UITextField on it, And that UITextField need to take only integer between 0-100.

how can I do that?

This is my code

```
let confirm = UIAlertController(title: "I want to reserve", message: "sometext", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            confirm.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in


                textField.placeholder = "Please fill the number between 0-100"

            })

            confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) in

                self.isReserve = true

                self.reservedIcon.alpha = 0
                self.reservedTitle.alpha = 0

                self.cancelReservedIcon.alpha = 1
                self.cancelReservedTitle.alpha = 1


            }))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let confirm = UIAlertController(title: "I want to reserve", message: "sometext", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        confirm.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in


            textField.placeholder = "Please fill the number between 0-100"

        })

        confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields![0]
        if textField.text != "1234" {  // change your if condition
           self.isReserve = true

            self.reservedIcon.alpha = 0
            self.reservedTitle.alpha = 0

            self.cancelReservedIcon.alpha = 1
            self.cancelReservedTitle.alpha = 1
        } else {
           // your else condition
        }
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your controller

Then your code :

```
    let confirm = UIAlertController(title: "I want to reserve", message: "sometext", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        confirm.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in


            textField.placeholder = "Please fill the number between 0-100"

        })
        let textfield = confirm.textFields?.first
        textfield?.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textfield?.delegate = self
        confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        confirm.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) in

            self.isReserve = true

            self.reservedIcon.alpha = 0
            self.reservedTitle.alpha = 0

            self.cancelReservedIcon.alpha = 1
            self.cancelReservedTitle.alpha = 1


        }))

        self.present(confirm, animated: true) {

        }
```

Add Textfield delegate :

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    return text.characters.count <= 100 // Your limit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shouldChangeCharactersInRange method and String extension to check if the input string contains number and control the text input between 0 to 100

```
    extension String  {
        var isNumber : Bool {
            get{
                return !self.isEmpty && self.stringWithoutWhitespaces.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
            }
        }

        var stringWithoutWhitespaces: String {
            return self.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        }

     }


    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // return true if the string only contains numeric characters
        var isValid = false
        if string.isNumber {
            if let num = Int(string.stringWithoutWhitespaces) {
                isValid = (num >= 0 && num <= 100)
            }
        }
        return isValid
     }
```